# Default applets on a fresh javacard

Tags: smartcard, javacard

I received a bunch of blank javacard (I mean I didn't write anything on them) some days ago as gift from a friend!

When I list its content using `gpj -list`,I receive the below output :

```
E:\Smart Card\gpj>gpj -list

E:\Smart Card\gpj>java -jar gpj.jar -list
Found terminals: [PC/SC terminal ACS CCID USB Reader 0]
Found card in terminal: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
ATR: 3B 68 00 00 00 73 C8 40 12 00 90 00

DEBUG: Command  APDU: 00 A4 04 00 08 A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00
DEBUG: Response APDU: 6F 10 84 08 A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 A5 04 9F 65 01 FF 90 0
0
Successfully selected Security Domain OP201a A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00

DEBUG: Command  APDU: 80 50 00 00 08 CF 3E F5 E1 32 B7 B2 6B
DEBUG: Response APDU: 00 00 11 60 01 00 8B 79 0A F9 FF 02 00 03 B5 00 CF 85 24 1
E BA 36 1E 49 97 56 F1 60 90 00
DEBUG: Command  APDU: 84 82 00 00 10 87 4B 25 EC 1E 8A E5 B4 A8 53 2E F0 13 BB 8
0 91
DEBUG: Response APDU: 90 00
DEBUG: Command  APDU: 84 82 00 00 08 87 4B 25 EC 1E 8A E5 B4
DEBUG: Response APDU: 90 00
DEBUG: Command  APDU: 80 F2 80 00 02 4F 00
DEBUG: Response APDU: 08 A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 01 9E 90 00
DEBUG: Command  APDU: 80 F2 80 00 02 4F 00
DEBUG: Response APDU: 08 A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 01 9E 90 00
DEBUG: Command  APDU: 80 F2 40 00 02 4F 00
DEBUG: Response APDU: 6A 88
DEBUG: Command  APDU: 80 F2 40 00 02 4F 00
DEBUG: Response APDU: 6A 88
DEBUG: Command  APDU: 80 F2 10 00 02 4F 00
DEBUG: Response APDU: 6A 81
DEBUG: Command  APDU: 80 F2 10 00 02 4F 00
DEBUG: Response APDU: 6A 81
DEBUG: Command  APDU: 80 F2 20 00 02 4F 00
DEBUG: Response APDU: 07 A0 00 00 00 03 53 50 01 00 06 A0 00 00 00 03 10 01 00 0
5 XX XX XX XX XX 01 00 08 XX XX XX XX XX 00 10 00 01 00 08 XX XX XX XX XX 00 30
00 01 00 05 XX XX XX XX XX 01 00 05 XX XX XX XX XX 01 00 06 A0 00 00 00 04 10 01
 00 06 A0 00 00 XX XX 01 01 00 07 A0 00 00 00 03 86 98 01 00 90 00
DEBUG: Command  APDU: 80 F2 20 00 02 4F 00
DEBUG: Response APDU: 07 A0 00 00 00 03 53 50 01 00 06 A0 00 00 00 03 10 01 00 0
5 XX XX XX XX XX 01 00 08 XX XX XX XX XX 00 10 00 01 00 08 XX XX XX XX XX 00 30
00 01 00 05 XX XX XX XX XX 01 00 05 XX XX XX XX XX 01 00 06 A0 00 00 00 04 10 01
 00 06 A0 00 00 XX XX 01 01 00 07 A0 00 00 00 03 86 98 01 00 90 00
AID: A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00                       |........|        ISD LC: 1 P
R: 0x9E

AID: A0 00 00 00 03 53 50                          |.....SP|         Exe LC: 1 P
R: 0x00

AID: A0 00 00 00 03 10                             |......|          Exe LC: 1 P
R: 0x00

AID: XX XX XX XX XX                                |1PAY.|           Exe LC: 1 P
R: 0x00

AID: XX XX XX XX XX 00 10 00                       |..e.....|        Exe LC: 1 P
R: 0x00

AID: XX XX XX XX XX 00 30 00                       |..e...0.|        Exe LC: 1 P
R: 0x00

AID: XX XX XX XX XX                                |..e..|           Exe LC: 1 P
R: 0x00

AID: XX XX XX XX XX                                |..e.0|           Exe LC: 1 P
R: 0x00

AID: A0 00 00 00 04 10                             |......|          Exe LC: 1 P
R: 0x00

AID: A0 00 00 XX XX 01                             |....3.|          Exe LC: 1 P
R: 0x00

AID: A0 00 00 00 03 86 98                          |.......|         Exe LC: 1 P
R: 0x00
```

The question is:

**How I can understand what is the functionality of each AIDs? I mean how can I work with them?**

Note : I don't know which company create these cards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first 5 bytes are the RID of the creator of the Applet. They are used as an identifier, [as specified in ISO/IEC 7816-5](http://www.ansi.org/other_services/registration_programs/rid.aspx?menuid=10).

So I guess your card is a card was generated for a specific payment service (RID: A0 00 00 XX XX). Unsurprisingly it has some payment related applets on it from VISA (RID: A0000003) and Mastercard (RID: A0000004).

For more info on how to use these kind of applets, you should probably consult the EMV specifications, and - of course - the unnamed payment service.

They are likely there because the Applet code is stored in the ROM, so the Applet does not have to be uploaded to the card. Making ROM masks is very expensive, but so is uploading an Applet millions of times.

Comment: Thank you dear Owlstead. About the last three lines : I can delete these applets, This mean that they didn't mask in ROM,Right? And why they must Some applets in ROM while it is very expensive?

Comment: First of all, *if* they are in ROM then 1) you are just looking at the *load file* - i.e. the code of the Applets, it won't take any memory other than ROM and 2) they cannot be fully removed. You would still need to instantiate them (through INSTALL for INSTALL) to make the Applets in there SELECTABLE. If you delete them you just remove them from Global Platform index (same as delete on Windows or Linux does). The reason why in ROM is in the last sentence.

Comment: So when I delete a masked in ROM applet, I can install it again, because the codes are still in the ROM. Is this true?

Comment: Probably a good idea, I can change my answer and comments if you like, comment below if you want this. Note that the changes will remain visible to (some) users, even after edits. Flag a mod if you want to have info removed permanently. No, as far as I know applets that have been removed completely from GP cannot be resurrected (even if the code is in ROM).

Comment: @TheGoodUser Anonymized it a bit, probably best to remove the related comments as well (about running etc.).

Comment: Comments Deleted :) Excuse me mr owlstead, Why did you anonymized just one of the AIDs? how did you understand which one is most important?!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60410/discussion-between-owlstead-and-thegooduser).